# python - install modules from source

Tags: python

I downloaded a `repo` from `github` and installed it in a `virtualenv` using `$python setup.py install` in the project dir.

This works fine. Now, when I open a file and induce an error, (like changing `return` to `lol`) it still installs fine. What is going on ? I wished to assert that my changes do not break the module and was hoping to install each time I make a change.

Answer (score 0):

With virtualenv you want to use pip to install packages. To install an editable version of the package, use the '-e' ('--editable') flag:

```
# source <myvirualenv>/bin/activate
# pip install -e <my-package-ref>
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing exactly that. It still installs fine despite the `lol`

Comment: The packaging / install is not meant to check for code correctness. That's what tests are for, and it's your duty to both write and run the tests before deploying.

Comment: But surely they should not install incorrect code ? Tests should test logic but the isn't the syntax the responsibility of the packager ?

Comment: @Hacketo Python is compiled to bytecode (the .pyc files) and syntax errors happen at compile time, not execution.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary the installer does not run the package's code (except of course for the packaging-related part). And

Comment: @Hacketo pyc files are created either when you explicitely ask for it or when a module is first imported there's no .pyc file or the .py file is newer than the .pyc one. The exceptions are 1. for the main script - it's compiled to bytecode but no .pyc file is written - and 2. when you only have the .pyc files (not the .py ones) in which case there's obviously no way to recompile anything.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary I repeat: code correctness is none of the installer's responsability, period. The only thing it could eventually detect anyway are syntax errors, which are so obvious that I fail to imagine how you (as a developer) could not notice them.

Comment: What do you think is the solution to my problem in that case ? How do I ensure my changes don't break my code ? Only tests ?

Comment: @Hacketo it's a NameError, not a SyntaxError, and it _does_ happens at execution time (notice the `RuntimeError` ?). Also not that in a REPL code is actually compiled on the fly (obviously). Now if you don't trust me feel free to read the source code.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary yes that's what tests (automated tests I mean) are for. You'd need them in any kind of language anyway as even the most bondage&discipline kind of language cannot detect logical errors.

Comment: Sure. the project I am playing with uses `tox` as the testing framework. Can you tell me how to view the failed (`xfailed` tests) ?